# Unable to install Informatica server

Tags: informatica-powercenter

unable to install informatica server in windows 10. After install anywhere screen nothing comes up.

ZeroGu6: Windows DLL failed to load
    at ZeroGa4.b(DashoA10*..)
    at ZeroGa4.b(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.b(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.a(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(DashoA10*..)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(DashoA10*..)

Answer (score 0):

While downloading the Informatica package you will have two setups provided. Separate setup would be provided for Informatica 10, and you have to use that setup. Other setup will not be compatible with windows 10.

[image]

You can find this inside, **V860964-01_1of8** directory

Comment: Yes I did, Now installed another version and  received  this error

! Cannot open C:\INFORMATICA\dac_win_11g_infa_win_64bit_101.z01
  The system cannot find the file specified.
! Seek error in the file

Comment: You have downloaded all the supporting zip files as well right, file having extensions from .z01 to .z08

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the supporting files location explicitely while extracting using [image]Winrar.

V860964-01_1of8 -- it has .zip file
V860964-01_2of8 -- it has .z01 file
V860964-01_3of8 -- it has .z02 file
V860964-01_4of8 -- it has .z03 file
V860964-01_5of8 -- it has .z04 file
V860964-01_6of8 -- it has .z05 file
V860964-01_7of8 -- it has .z06 file
V860964-01_8of8 -- it has .z07 file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you see this error:
! Cannot open D:\Informatica\Informatica\V76290-01_4of4\dac_win_11g_infa_win_64bit_961.zip.z01! Seek error in the file

1. Unzip files all in one place (not in different folders, the same folder for all the files)
2. then try to unzip again.
3. it works for me.